# JavaScript : Getting Tag name of a certain innerHtml text

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml, tagname

I will really appreciate you if you can help me with the following problem.
Suppose that I know the "Home" text but now I want to catch where is it in. Means is it in the div tag or in a level tag .Here you should help me to find the div tag and it's id "ey".

```
<div id="ey">
<ul>
<li>
  <a href="korstone.htm">Home</a>
</li>
</ul>

<ul>
<li>
  <a href="#">About us</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: What did you edited @Sazid ? Bro i can't understand . And why did you edited my question.

Comment: I just removed the 'blockquote' things you posted along. Everything else is just fine. :D

Comment: Thanks, But I knew that if I want to insert code then have to place it between blockquote.

Comment: Just, place some code, select them and press Ctrl-K. No need to place within any quotes :)

Comment: In response to your question in the comments below about IDs : ob.id='myid';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

lets' say you start with by passing the 'a' element t a function onclick.

```
<a onclick='findWhereIAm(this)'>blah blah</a>
```

You then can find out what it's in by using the parentNode property. And you can travel up the chain of parents by using a loop.

```
function findWhereIAm(element){
  var parent=element.parentNode;
  while(parent.nodeName!="BODY"){
      if(parent.id=='whatever value you are checking'){
          //do your stuff
         alert(parent.id);

         //break or you'll keep looping through
         break;
     }
     parent=parent.parentNode.
}
}
```

**EDIT**

```
var as=document.getElementsByTagName('a');
var element;
for(var i=0;i<as.length;i++){
     if(as[i].innerHTML=='Home'){
         element=as[i];
         break;
      }
}

 if(element){
      var parent=element.parentNode;
      while(parent.nodeName!="BODY"){
         if(parent.id=='whatever value you are checking'){
          //do your stuff
         alert(parent.id);

         //break or you'll keep looping through
         break;
     }
     parent=parent.parentNode.
}

 }
```

Comment: But here where do you have use my known innerHtml text "Home" in condition. i do not want to use onclick() function. Please try to understand the question first.Thanks @user2782001

Comment: I understand the question. I just don't want to do ALL the work for you. Come on guy. Use document.getElementsByTagName('a') to get all the links, then loop through them and check the .innerHTML properties to see if it matches.

Comment: If you have NO idea what tag your HOME is in, then you have to loop through them all using document.getElementsByTagName('*');

Comment: Thanks , i have understood the method .I have accepted your method .But still is not clear to me by looping I will find the anchor tag ok .But how to get the parent div ,li tag .With the above code? answer me please.@user2788001

Comment: The edit should help you out. I think you can adjust it to suit whatever specifically you are tring to do.

Comment: One thing can you help me . I know that ob.className='newclass' is used to change the class of a tag but If I want to change the ID then what I have to use rather than "className=" . @user2782001

Answer (score 0):

The following will tell you the ID:

```
$("*:contains('Home')").closest("div").prop("id")
```

This will tell you the tag name

```
$("*:contains('Home')").closest("div").prop("tagName")
```

Comment: This questions wasn't tagged with jquery, you should specify that this works with jquery

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<a onclick='search(this)'>home</a>


    function serach(el){
    var a = el.parent('#ey');
    console.log(a)
    }
```